# How can i catch referer value dynamically changing in request header

Tags: java, json, rest, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I want to add referer value into my code but when i check it from network tab through inspect of Chrome, referer value is not constant, it's always changing. How can i catch and define it in my code ? Is there a way to set the referer as parameter in request header ?

I'm using RestAssure framework by using Java.

```
   RestAssured.baseURI="https://test-v2-api.mykredit.com/api/customer/light";
    //RestAssured.baseURI="https://test-v2-api.mykredit.com/api/membership";
    RequestSpecification httpRequest2 = RestAssured.given();
    JSONObject requestparam2 = new JSONObject();
    System.out.println(mobilenum.substring(5)); 
    requestparam2.put("pin",mobilenum.substring(5));
    
    httpRequest2.header("Content-Type","application/json; charset=utf-8");
    httpRequest2.body(requestparam2.toJSONString());
    
    //Response response = httpRequest2.request(Method.POST,"/login");
    Response response = httpRequest2.request(Method.POST,"/pinValidate");
    String responseBody = response.getBody().asString();
    System.out.println(responseBody);
    
    int status = response.getStatusCode();
    System.out.println("Status"+" "+status);
    Assert.assertEquals(status, 200);
    
}
```

[image: referer]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getHeader(String name)` method in `io.restassured.response` ([java documentation](https://www.javadoc.io/static/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/3.0.1/io/restassured/response/ResponseOptions.html#getHeaders--)) to retrieve values from response headers.

```
Response response = httpRequest2.request(Method.POST,"/pinValidate");
String referer = response.getHeader("referer");
```

imports;

```
import io.restassured.response.Response;
```

You can use the `header(String name)` method as well.

---

**UPDATE**

You can use `getHeaders()` method in `io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl` ([Java documentation](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/latest/io/restassured/internal/RequestSpecificationImpl.html#getHeaders--)) to retrieve request headers.

```
Response response = httpRequest2.request(Method.POST,"/pinValidate");
String refererValue = ((RequestSpecificationImpl) httpRequest2).getHeaders().get("referer").getValue();
```

imports;

```
import io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl;
```

Comment: thanks for answer but i didn't get your point. referer value is located in request header not in reponse header.